# What is this? Found crawling across ground under oak tree. Six arms waving, I broke off 1 trying to pick it up. Less than 1 inch long

Tags: species-identification, species

Crawled like snail.  No slime trail.  Less than one inch.  Six arms, I broke one off.

[image]

Comment: Where in the world is that species located? And at which season?

Comment: Hi D.J., welcome to Bio.SE! Please add a location, approximate size, and preferably additional (clearer) photos of your specimen. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That is a [Hag](https://www.butterfliesandmoths.org/species/Phobetron-pithecium) [moth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phobetron_pithecium) [caterpillar](https://bugguide.net/node/view/257)

[image: Hag moth caterpillar]

Don't touch.